# Need a help how to make same calculations with all values from text or excel and export it

Tags: python, excel

Sup folks, well I have a big problem. First of all I'm new in python (atm 3.x). I need a help to figure out, how to pick correct data exactly for calculations (Sorry for my english). For eg.:
I have a excel file with data:

[My excel data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsYLB.jpg)

I can count this manually for e.g

```
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('angles.xls')
sheet = book.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
angle = sheet['A1'].value
minute = sheet['B1'].value
seconds = sheet['C1'].value
calculations = angle + minute/60 +  seconds/60
```

and also export this

```
sys.stdout = open(input("name it :"), 'w')
print(calculations)
```

But I cant figure out how to make that it could automaticaly count for next values, A2,B2,C2..... A7,B7,C7...... till all existing values. And after all, instead of 1 result, I could get all. E.g. If there were 10 calculations from A1,B1,C1........ A10,B10,C10 and get 10 calculations. If its easier it also can be a text data.

thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over each row to do this. Just get number of rows, and simple for loop will be enough. For example:

```
book = openpyxl.load_workbook('excel.xlsx')

sheet = book.active

for row_i in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
     deg_value = sheet.cell(row=row_i, column=1).value
     min_value = sheet.cell(row=row_i, column=2).value
     sec_value = sheet.cell(row=row_i, column=3).value
     print(deg_value, min_value, sec_value)
```